# terraform v12 data source throwing multiple results

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

just want to ask if you encountered this error and if you can share on how you solved it.

```
Error: Search returned 8 results, please revise so only one is returned
on ../module/ecs-task/data.tf line 31, in data "aws_efs_file_system" "efs":
  31: data "aws_efs_file_system" "efs" {
```

data.tf has these block from lines 31-35

```
  data "aws_efs_file_system" "efs" {
  tags = {
    Name = "${lower(var.MY_EFS_ID)}-${lower(var.TYPE)}}-efs"
  }
}
```

the main tf code that calls the data.tf

```
resource "aws_ecs_task_definition" "task_definition" {
  family                   = "${lower(var.MY_FAMILY_ID)}-${lower(var.TYPE)}}-efs"
  network_mode             = "awsvpc"
  cpu                      = var.CPU
  memory                   = var.MEMORY
  requires_compatibilities = ["FARGATE"]
  container_definitions    = data.template_file.ecs_template.rendered
  execution_role_arn       = data.iam_role.ecs_exec_role.arn
  task_role_arn            = data.iam_role.ecs_exec_role.arn
  volume {
      name  = "my-volume"
      efs_volume_configuration {
        file_system_id = data.aws_efs_file_system.efs.id
        root_directory          = "/pogi"
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: To solve it you must ensure that data source returns only one result.

Comment: @Marcin - indeed, we have this unique efs that has that unique tag. I'm not sure why its giving 8 results.

Comment: @Marcin - upon checking all EFS deployed on our vpc are 8, seems like relevant on the error

Comment: The error msg writes `"aws_efs_file_system" "efs"`, but your question provides different data source named `myefs`. So its difficult to try to guess what's wrong.

Comment: @Marcin - it was a typo, updated my post, however still getting same output

Comment: From this https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/efs_file_system, I think data source aws_efs_file_system does not export id and you can pass this id from local ( local.aws_efs_file_system_id )

Comment: We need to see the `name` tag for the eight EFS in the VPC.

Comment: @FranxiHidro seems like it really didn't provide id via data source, thanks too for your tip!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@FranxiHidro seems like it really didn't provide id via data source, thanks too for your tip!